# How to perform repetitive tasks in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, sextante-qgis-plugin, spatial-join

I am trying to do a treatment on many feature files, so I would like to automate it.

In fact, I have one shapefile with the spatial distribution of some species, and one with vegetation type.

I would like to select (by attribute) one species in the Species Shapefile, then to select (by locality) all vegetation areas which intersect with their distribution area. Finally, I would like to have a shapefile with, as name, the species name, and with attributes and forms of the frequented vegetation types. And I would like to repeat this for all species (more than 100), and if possible do this in an easy manner (so it could be done by another person).

I have already tried this task using Sextante plugin, but I can't have the species name as a shapefile name at the end.

Can someone suggest a method for this?

Comment: From your description the entire work would be more suitable for a full-featured geodatabase like PostGIS or SpatiaLite. But a complete solution to perform what you need may be not trivial.

Answer (score 5):

This blog entry might help to understand how to do it in SEXTANTE:

http://qgissextante.blogspot.fr/2013/01/using-selection-algorithms.html

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I want to try it, but I am not expert on this kind of script, so can you explain what we have to do with this script? where should we have to copy it? thanks.

Comment: Great, thank you very much, I tried it (through the Python Console) and it works well. The next step, I will try to adapt it as a Sextante modeler.
It is damage that there is no such command in such a tool as Sextante (set the name of the output file with some variables).

Answer (score 3):

This calls for a little script. To make it reproducible I would try to accomplish it in [R](http://cran.r-project.org/). It should also be possible with QGis and Sextante by using the batch-execution (rightclick on function) in a Sextante model. Here you could first use the vector intersection tool and afterwards some kind of spatial join.

In R i would try it like this. You might have to modify the code as i don't know your data structure and variables.

```php
library(raster);library(rgdal);library(sp)         # Load in required packages

vegetation <- readOGR("H:/Examplefolder",          # To load a vegetation polygon shape here 
                      "vegi")                      # called vegi.shp    

setwd(harddriveD)                                  # Now, switch to the directory containing your species shapes
                                                   # and use the following code 
species_files <- grep( ".shp",                     # to extract all shape names
                       dir(),
                       ignore.case=T,
                       value=T)

                                                   # Now read in your speciesfiles in a loop 
for(name in species_files){                        # and do a  vegetation data
                                                   # overlay with your basename
    spec_name <- strsplit(name,split=".shp")[[1]]  # to get only the load in
                                                   # your species name shape. 

    spec_shp <- readOGR(".",spec_name)             # I assume that you have point data. Otherwise change the code.
    ov <- over(spec_shp,vegetation)                # Make a overlay with your vegetation data, 
                                                   # returns a dataframe of the overlaying vegetation shape attributes, 
                                                   # which are within your species shape. 
                                                   # This dataframe has the same number of rows as your input species shape. 
   cd <- coordinates(spec_shp);                    # Therefore you could just append the needed information to your species shape.
   proj <- proj4string(spec_shp)                   # save coordinates and proj.

                                                   # Append your vegetation data to your species shape
   spec_shp$Vegetation <- ov$ShrubSpecies          # Or whatever you want to get. 

   spp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(                  # In the end export your shape again. 
                    coords=cd,                     # I would advise you to use a different folder. 
                    data=as.data.frame(spec_shp),  # In case you have polygons instead of Point data
                    proj4string=CRS(proj) )        # use the SpatialPolygonDataFrame function. -> help ?SpatialPolygonDataFrame
  writeOGR(spp,                                    #Should result in a new shape 
           "foldername",                           # which has your species name.
           spec_name,
           driver="ESRI Shapefile")                      

}
```

I've made many assumption about your goal and the structure of your dataset. Most likely you have to correct the code to your needs before trying it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try it. My species data are in polygon (species distribution), but I think it's maybe quite the same? many thanks

Comment: You just need to change some function (SpatialPolygonsDataFrame for instance) and most likely over returns a list of dataframes or something else.